# Html.ActionLink helper creating incorrect link when trying to apply ID

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm getting an odd result when trying to assign an ID attribute to an [a] tag created via the Razor @Html.ActionLink helper

My original code was this:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Create New Order", "Index", "NewOrder")
```

This works correctly and creates a link as http://www.mysite.com/NewOrder but I want to add an ID tag to my element.

I then tried this

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Create New Order", "Index", "NewOrder", new {@id = "orderlink"})
```

This creates a link of http://www.mysite.com/Orders?Length=8

**UPDATE:**

When I use the solution provided,

@Html.ActionLink("Create New Order", "Index", "NewOrder", new { @id = "orderlink" }, null)

I get a link that looks like this:
http://www.mysite.com/NewOrder/Index/orderlink

I don't want the orderlink added to my link/route. I want it added to the [a] tags attributes. See the top of the question.

I want to get this:

```
 <a id="orderlink" href="/tcap/NewOrder/Index" >Create New Order</a>
```

Comment: what is your controller name and action names ?

Comment: Controller is NewOrder, Action is Index

Comment: @Shyju Almost there. This gives my [a] tag the correct value for the href attribute, but I need to set the id attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972.aspx) overload.

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

So your code will be

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Create New Order", "Index", "NewOrder", 
              new {@id = "orderlink"},null)
```

**EDIT :** As per your comment/ updated question

Use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505070) overload

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Create New Order", "Index", "NewOrder")
```

this will give you  `mysite.com/NewOrder/Index` url

**EDIT2** : 
If you want,  `<a id="orderlink" href="/tcap/NewOrder/Index" >Create New Order</a>`

Use this, pass HTML attributes as the fifth parameter of [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972.aspx) overload

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New Order", "Index", 
            "NewOrder",null,new {@id="orderlink"})
```

Comment: +1 too fast, was gonna 'paste' an answer identical to this from an answer i gave the other day :)

Comment: @jimtollan: Thanks :) But i am caught by the Reputation cap policy for the day ! :(

Comment: Heh.  I stumbled across that very issue last night.

Comment: Giovanni - everything is beautiful (in its own way - hmm feel a song coming on ):)

Comment: what is your controller name ? Is that "NewOrder" ?

Comment: @Shyju Correct. but I need the <a> tag that is created to have an id of orderlink.  <a id="orderlink" href="/mysite/NewOrder/Index" >Create New Order</a>

Comment: @Shyju OK, that did it. Thanks so much. It was driving me crazy.

Comment: @JeffReddy: Next time, when writing the question, try to include all relevant details in the first time itself. Good luck & Thanks :)

Comment: @Shyju If you read the first line of my question, you can see I explicitly asked for the ID attribute for the A tag.

Answer (score 2):

answered this the other day here:

[ASP.NET MVC basic routing with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767058/asp-net-mvc-basic-routing-with-parameters/11767143#11767143)

in a nutshell, add a final null parameter to the overload:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New Order", "Index", "NewOrder", 
                  new {@id = "orderlink"}, null)
```

Adding the `null` as the final param (`htmlAttributes`) is all that's missing for you in this scenario (there are 9 overloads for Html.ActionLink, so it's VERY easy to miss the correct implementation).